# Best Email notifier to replace standard Geary

Tags: pantheon-mail, notifications

As it is written in other post, To make Geary work,it is necessary to change gmail setting to less secure connection.

Is there any secure email notifier?

searching in Software Center results in some applications, however I am not sure which one is secure and works fine.

Comment: It can be nice to have a program with notifier on top panel

Comment: OP, list type questions are generally discouraged on StackExchange since there is no real answer here. For software recommendations, a better place to ask might be Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos or Google+: https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/104613975513761463450

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at Nylas N1: https://www.nylas.com/n1. Its free and is open source.

Comment: how is security for this software?

Comment: N1 uses OAuth to authenticate rather than IMAP authentication. That means you won't have to turn on the "less secure" option in Gmail. Here's a bit more on what exactly Google means by "less secure": http://security.stackexchange.com/a/72371

Comment: I installed the program. it is fine. I wish there was a notifier on top panel with number of unread emails.